# Custom layout for Spinner item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner, android-alertdialog

I have a spinner within alert dialog. I wanted to reduce padding between spinner items and hence I implemented following:

**spinner_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="#fff" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCust"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

**Activity code contains following:**

```
spinner= (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
String arr[] = { "1", "2", "3" };
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
CameraActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_row, R.id.tvCust,arr);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

---

Now as you can see in below screenshot, radio button is getting displayed on spinner which is actually a part of `spinner_row.xml`. Note that textview width is 200dp while spinner is only 130dp long, so that radio button should not have been displayed on spinner. How can I remove it?

Also, when I click any of the spinner item, spinner pop-up doesn't get disappeared as expected.(note all 3 check-boxes are checked in spinner items list). `setOnItemSelectedListener` is not getting called on item click.

Any help appreciated.

[image: screenshot]

### Edit 1

As per **farrukh**'s suggestion, I tried his code and following is the result.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: *so that radio button should not have been displayed on spinner.* - and why not? It's in the layout, its width doesn't matter as you use a layout which stacks children. I would recommned something but I don't understand what you want to do. *Also, when I click any of the spinner item, spinner pop-up doesn't get disappeared as expected* - add `android:focusable="false"` for the `RadioButton` in the xml layout.

Comment: @Luksprog : Referring to edited question screenshot, text should be left align where as radio button should be right aligned and radio button should not be displayed on spinner. Any way to achieve this?

Comment: adding `android:focusable="false"` doesn't change anything. Strange enough, applying custom background to spinner solves the issue of pop-up disappearance after any of the radio button is clicked.

Comment: EDIT to above comment : adding `android:focusable="false"` doesn't change anything. Strange enough, applying custom background to spinner solves the issue of pop-up disappearance if any of the text is clicked but doesn't disappear if radio button is clicked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have this

[image]

and this

[image]

with these code of xml

xml for adapter named spinadapt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:background="#fff" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCust"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and main layout named activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:hint="Select item"
    android:background="@drawable/spin"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and java code is class named MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    Spinner sp;
    TextView tv;
    String[]  counting={"One","Two","Three","Four"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            sp=new Spinner(this);
            tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {                       
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            sp.performClick();
                        }
                });
            sp.setAdapter(new Adapter(MainActivity.this, counting));
            sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
                        {
                            tv.setText(counting[arg2]);
                        }
                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
                        {
                        }
                });
        }
}
```

and adapter class named Adapter.java

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    LayoutInflater inflator;
    String[] mCounting;

    public Adapter( Context context ,String[] counting)
        {
            inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            mCounting=counting;
        }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
        {
            return mCounting.length;
        }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
        {
            return null;
        }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
        {
            return 0;
        }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.spinadapt, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCust);
            tv.setText(Integer.toString(position));
            return convertView;
        }
}
```

this is working perfect

hope this will help

Comment: please let me know which is your desired screen  the first one??

Comment: none of the two. Text should be at extreme left and radio button should be at extreme right.

Comment: Thanks for the code. But I have already mentioned that I don't want to show radio button on spinner (as your screenshot part 1 suggests)...

Comment: have alook at editted code this is the only way to do that the default spinner must show the complete row of your list

Comment: in `activity_main.xml`, `android:background="@drawable/spin"` refers to what?

Comment: So actually, spinner does show that radio button. But u r overlapping another image over it. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: yes i have replaced spinner with text view in xml and create a spinner on java at runtime and on clicking on text view we are populating the list of spinner

Comment: SO I can show any default text for spinner just like you are showing "Select Item" currently.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32802/discussion-between-farrukh-and-gama)