# Android Spinner suggestions needed

Tags: java, android

I am using spinner in my layout and its appearance is as follows:

[image]

I want to increase the spinner size to make it more attractive and visible.

here is spinner xml and activity snippet.

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_room"
    android:layout_below="@id/Toolbar_Room"
    android:textSize="52sp"
    android:prompt="@string/room_prompt"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:dropDownSelector="@drawable/img_small_box_green"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"></Spinner>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407626/custom-layout-for-spinner-item here you go.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom layout for your Spinner and inflate it through an adapter.
Check out this.
http://abhiandroid.com/ui/custom-spinner-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

I have created spinner with card view check this you may like this design.

[image]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/margin_2"
    app:contentPaddingBottom="@dimen/margin_5"
    app:contentPaddingTop="@dimen/margin_5">


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp_filter_status"
        style="@style/Widget.Spinner"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_expand_black"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="0dp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**drawable/spinner_expand_black**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="@dimen/margin_1"
                android:left="@dimen/margin_1"
                android:right="@dimen/margin_1"
                android:top="@dimen/margin_1" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="end"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_action_expand_more" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

@mipmap/ic_action_expand_more is image of bottom arrow you can find from material icon site.

**Style**

```
<style name="Widget.Spinner" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown">
        <item name="android:background">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
        <item name="overlapAnchor">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_16</item>
        <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>
        <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score -2):

put your `Spinner` inside `CardView`.
it will look more better.