# how to Style a Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am new to `Android` and was working with `Spinner`. I wanted to know that how can we style the `Spinner` items? Change the `fontFamily` of the items, `textColor`, `textSize`.
 Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: use a custom spinner item and set it to spinneradapter.. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407626/custom-layout-for-spinner-item

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom layout for Spinner item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407626/custom-layout-for-spinner-item)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a custom layout

**my_spinner_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/clear_sans_regular"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:textColor="@color/tealish"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

here you can customize according to your need , and then use it inside your adapter

```
Spinner yourSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.your_spinner_id;
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("list 1");
list.add("list 2");
list.add("list 3");
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.my_spinner_layout, list);   //use your custom layout like this
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_spinner_layout);
yourSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: @rohan-vaish hope it helps you mate

Comment: So this kind of worked. The styles are applied to the spinner field, but not to the items inside the Drop Down list. @Thunder

Comment: Pass the same layout to `#setDropDownViewResource()`.

Comment: @ADM yes , done sir.

Comment: that is already done. How do I style the dropdown items?

Comment: dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_spinner_layout);
 do this

Comment: inside your setDropDownViewResource also pass your same layout.

Comment: Yeah I got that. I didn't realize it before. My bad.Thanks. @ADM