# How to create a drop-down list in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, drop-down-menu, android-spinner

I am trying to create a drop-down list for an activity in Android Studio. I have tried using the Spinner.

Here is my xml code:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>
```

Here is my Java code:

```
Spinner dropdown = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
String[] items = new String[]{"1", "2", "3"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is a screenshot of what it looks like:
[image: screenshot of Spinner]

As you can see, the drop-down list appears as a pop-up, however, I want the drop-down list to appear in a different way. See the image below as an example of what I want:

[image: drop-down list]

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could do this?

Comment: There is nothing built into android that does this, it would have to be a custom implementation

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you have any ideas on how I could implement this?

Answer (score 2):

Actually it does look like there is a way with the Material design library called [ExposedDropdownMenu](https://www.material.io/components/menus/android#exposed-dropdown-menus)

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/label">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="none"
    />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Obviously this is with TextInput and not a spinner so there will still be some custom logic to prevent typing if you dont want that

I personally have not tried it myself but it looks like what you want

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

As @tyczj said, that is android's default layout that is showing, so there are some alternatives:

1. Create tour own [custom layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407626/custom-layout-for-spinner-item)
2. Use an external library like [SearchableSpinner](https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner), it incorporates the search function and the item layout is similar from what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have found a useful example for a ComboBox/Spinner on Android:

https://abhiandroid.com/ui/spinner

Here is the code:

https://github.com/abhisheksaini4/SpinnerExamples/blob/master/SpinnerExamples.7z

The main codes include MainActivity.java:

```
package example.abhiandriod.spinnerexample;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

    String[] bankNames={"BOI","SBI","HDFC","PNB","OBC"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Getting the instance of Spinner and applying OnItemSelectedListener on it
        Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.simpleSpinner);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        //Creating the ArrayAdapter instance having the bank name list
        ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,bankNames);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        //Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner
        spin.setAdapter(aa);
    }


    //Performing action onItemSelected and onNothing selected
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), bankNames[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/simpleSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`menu_main.xml`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

And `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="example.abhiandriod.spinnerexample" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```